# <div> is automatically replace with <span>

Tags: html, view-source

trying to write "div" tag after the "a" but whenever I check this piece of code by viewing source, it is automatically replaced with "span". I am using HTML5 and checking this code in firefox 42. nd I had already checked it in html validator.

```
<a href="services.php" class="list-group-item block-active"> Services 
    <div class="icon-parent">
        <div class="default-block text-center other-bg block-active">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                <i class="fa fa-code-fork fa-stack-1x"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-stack-1x"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you post what it appears when you view the code?

Comment: please post your css as well, if you had written any class on your own related to above logic

Comment: Try setting the doctype at the top of your document to `<!DOCTYPE html>`, this will instruct browsers to use the html5 standard when rendering.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAMUK2ut1MFH5qz53vHhYpuEaHSQ6YPbgI8

Answer (score 0):

Run your HTML through a validator.

The `a` element is an in-line element that can't hold `block` level elements.  Without knowing the browser and doctype, an exact answer can't be given because different browsers are allowed to auto-correct bad HTML4 however they want.

HTML5 should be standardized.

Comment: em already using html5 and checking this code in firfox 42 and my html markup starts with    <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved now!
Thanks everyone for your suggestion, we were struggling on this error from last 3 days but solution was very simpe, an inner ending span was missing which causes this error.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't nest divs within an anchor.

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a href="services.php">Services</a>
        <!-- your icon stuff here -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually with html5 you can

Comment: HTML5 [allows](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) anchors to wrap block elements

Comment: Also, the user is using Bootstrap css, which will allow formatting based on the user choice..In his case, it is actually shown as menu item

Comment: I didn't say you can't I said you shouldn't, it also adversely affects SEO.